# IPython won't start with locally installed Python 3.5

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I am on a linux system that only has Python 2.7 installed globally. I have installed Anaconda with Python 3.5 in my home folder. I also installed the latest version of IPython using `conda install ipython`. When running `ipython` at the console, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mateinfo/vlad/anaconda3/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    import IPython
  File "/home/mateinfo/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/home/mateinfo/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "/home/mateinfo/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pickleshare import PickleShareDB
  File "/home/mateinfo/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pickleshare.py", line 41, in <module>
    from path import path as Path
  File "/opt/pcm/lib/python/path.py", line 919
    def mkdir(self, mode=0777):
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is with the used `path` module, which seems to be from Python 2.7, since it uses the old octal format `0777`.

How can I get IPython working under this setup?

I have this in my `.bashrc`:

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.0.0 installer
export PATH="/home/mateinfo/vlad/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/mateinfo/vlad/anaconda3/lib:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/mateinfo/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5:$PATH"
```

Only the first line was added by the Anaconda installer, the other 2 were added by me, with no success.

Comment: The only line needed is the `bin` folder. Nothing more. The problem lays somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have a `PYTHONPATH` set? If yes, do `unset PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @MaxNoe that was it. I had no idea it was set though. If you'll make an answer out of it I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set to a location where a python2 library resides.

As general recommendation, never use this variable. Create proper `setup.py` scripts for your libraries.

To get rid of it, you can do `unset PYTHONPATH` or eliminate anything that sets this variable in your `.bashrc`.